# All font sizes change when manually typing 2011 into url and going to archive page

Tags: urls, archives

I am developing a site on MAMP and everything is going fine except that I thought I would check how all the default archive pages look.  I typed 2011 at the end of the base url and it retrieved a yearly archive as expected.

The problem is that the font sizes of every element change to a smaller size.  I understand that there are different headings in the archives, but this problem affects the main nave menu, normal li items ... everything.

Has anyone had this happen to them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your browser’s debugger to find the applied CSS rules. Usually there are some some unclosed elements and/or some badly written CSS rules like `#content * { font-size: .9em }`.
It’s not a WordPress problem. :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and for the reminder to do what I always tell my friends to do - check everything.  It ended up being a duplicate class date that had a font size set and when the archive page set the body class to `<body class="archive date">` it grabbed that font size and since the sizes were in ems the mistake cascaded through the page.  Working now.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your archives.php template file and see what CSS and HTML is involved, and use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or use the developer tools in [Chrome](https://developers.chrome.com/devtools/) or [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) or [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673541(v=vs.85).aspx) to see the active CSS and HTML.

Comment: As I said above, thank you for reminding me to check everything.  I also validated my CSS in the process.